# Looping within a coroutine

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have written the following snippet in order to play five clicking sounds resembling a rotating wheel.

How can I make a loop out of it, so that the clicks keep on playing until I call the stop function at the bottom?

I toggled on the loop feature on each sound file, but they still each play only once...

```c#
public void PlayClickSounds()
{
    StartCoroutine( ClickSounds(0.5f) );
}

private IEnumerator ClickSounds(float clipsGapDuration)
{
    Play(SpinningSoundClick1);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(clipsGapDuration);                      
    Play(SpinningSoundClick2);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(clipsGapDuration);
    Play(SpinningSoundClick3);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(clipsGapDuration);
    Play(SpinningSoundClick4);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(clipsGapDuration);
    Play(SpinningSoundClick5);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(clipsGapDuration);
}

public void StopClickSounds()
{
    StopCoroutine( SpinningClickSounds(0.5f) );
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a while-loop? In the argument you could just use "true", since you stop the coroutine externaly.

Comment: oh I see... Thank you, I will try that!

Comment: @T.Grumser If you include your suggestion/solution in the answer section, I can accept as the answer that helped me!

Comment: That's very kind, but for such a small effort, to know i could help is enough of a reward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `while` loop. I don't see your setup but you should also rather use a list like e.g.

```c#
[SerializeField] private List<AudioClip> _boostWheelSpinningSoundClicks = new List<AudioClip>();

private int _currentIndex;
private Coroutine _currentRoutine;

public void PlayClickSounds()
{
    if(_currentRoutine != null) 
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Already playing");
        return;
    }

    _currentRoutine = StartCoroutine(ClickSounds(0.5f));
}

private IEnumerator ClickSounds(float clipsGapDuration)
{
    // This looks dangerous but is allowed in 
    // Coroutines as long as you yield somewhere inside
    while(true)
    {
        _currentIndex = (_currentIndex + 1) % _boostWheelSpinningSoundClicks.Count;

        var currentClip = _boostWheelSpinningSoundClicks[_currentIndex];
        Play(currentClip);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(clipsGapDuration);                      
    }
}

public void StopClickSounds()
{
    if(_currentRoutine == null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Not playing");
        return;
    }

    StopCoroutine(_currentRoutine);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are various options for how you can achieve that. You can use while loop, you can call a coroutine from a coroutine.

This is an example while.

```
private bool _isClipPlaying;
private IEnumerator ClickSounds(float clipsGapDuration)
{
    while(_isClipPlaying){
        Play(boostWheelSpinningSoundClick1);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(clipsGapDuration);                      
        Play(boostWheelSpinningSoundClick2);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(clipsGapDuration);
        Play(boostWheelSpinningSoundClick3);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(clipsGapDuration);
        Play(boostWheelSpinningSoundClick4);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(clipsGapDuration);
        Play(boostWheelSpinningSoundClick5);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(clipsGapDuration);
    }
}

public void PlayClickSounds()
{
    _isClipPlaying = true;
    StartCoroutine( ClickSounds(0.5f) );
}

public void StopClickSounds()
{
    _isClipPlaying = false;
}
```

Another option is to call coroutine after that.

```
private IEnumerator ClickSounds(float clipsGapDuration)
{
    Play(boostWheelSpinningSoundClick1);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(clipsGapDuration);                      
    Play(boostWheelSpinningSoundClick2);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(clipsGapDuration);
    Play(boostWheelSpinningSoundClick3);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(clipsGapDuration);
    Play(boostWheelSpinningSoundClick4);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(clipsGapDuration);
    Play(boostWheelSpinningSoundClick5);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(clipsGapDuration);
    StartCoroutine(ClickSounds(clipsGapDuration));
}
```

I would suggest using list for click sounds as it will be more readable.